# No 'Remove Attachments' button in full-screen Mac Mail?

Tags: mail.app, attachments

I often use the 'remove attachments' button in Mac Mail when replying to a message.  However I've noticed that when composing a reply in full-screen mode, this button disappears.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to get the same function?  I could remove the attachments one at a time but that's a pain if there are multiple attachments in the message.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of said button? I'm having an idea of what you want and how to help but I don't have such a button.